# Consuming values from few directives in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have following directive:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('ngBootstrapSelect', () => ({
     templateUrl: 'components/bootstrap-select/bootstrap-select.html',
     replace: 'true',
     restrict: 'EA',
     scope: {
       value: '=',
       options: '=',
       name: '@'
     },
     link: function(scope, $elem, $attrs) {

       scope.$watch($attrs.ngModel, function (newVal) {
         scope.$evalAsync(function () {
           if (!$attrs.ngOptions || /track by/.test($attrs.ngOptions)) $elem.val(newVal);
           $elem.selectpicker('refresh');
         });
       });

       scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
         scope.$evalAsync(function () {
            $elem.selectpicker('destroy');
         });
       });

     }
   }));
```

and template:

```
<select class="btn-group bootstrap-select bs-select form-control pull-right" ng-model="value" ng-options="option as option for option in options" data-width="250px" data-live-search="true" data-size="8" >
   <option value="">SELECT {{ name | uppercase}}</option>
</select>
```

I'm creating few components based on that directive on one page. How I can consume values from all components that are created on single page when user click on button?

I thought about creating $broadcast and in controller consume data from each broadcast but in that case it's possible that I won't get data from all components and I need data from all of them.

Comment: So if I get you right, you have multiple `ngBootstrapSelect` elements that uses your directive in your page and you want to get all their values when you click on a button. Is that right ?

Comment: @Elfayer that's right. Only exception of that is that button is not part of that directive. I wanted to run function on ng-click to get data from compontents and send $http request.

Comment: So you have corresponding models you bind to each element. What is the problem then to use those models?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a value from your controller with the isolated scope of your directive (by using `=` symbol). So in your scenario, just bind those values from your directives to a property of your scope and you will be able to access to those whenever you want (ng-click for example).

Is that ok for you ?